# Metor + Semantic UI : variable @googleProtocol is undefined

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

I've created a fresh project with Meteor and I'm trying to integrate Semantic UI, I've walked through the steps here
https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/integrations.html
but I'm getting this problem after installing the sematicui and postcss packages :

```
   While processing files with less (for target web.browser):
   client/lib/semantic-ui/definitions/globals/site.import.less:29: variable
   @googleProtocol is undefined
   error: variable @googleProtocol is undefined
```

The Meteor version is 1.10.2, the packages.json looks like this;

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.1",
    "postcss": "^6.0.22",
    "postcss-load-config": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {
        "browsers": [
          "last 2 versions"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've got the same error. Did you had any luck on solving this issue? Looks like you also use the fix from [this post](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor/issues/140) to solve the `Cannot find module 'postcss-load-config'` error. But how to deal with the googleProtocol issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was painful. Apparently the problem i[s the version of less](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-LESS/issues/30) and some [incompatibility with juliancwirko:postcss package and meteor](https://github.com/juliancwirko/meteor-postcss) (2.0 in my case). The solution I found was the following:

1. meteor npm install --save-dev postcss@6.0.22 postcss-load-config@1.2.0
2. npm install less@2.7.3 --save-dev

After these considerations, it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Same error here, for me this worked:

```
meteor install semantic:ui
meteor install less@2.8.0
```